# java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /tmp/jaas-5830500690688188948.conf while EKS pod trying to access EBS volume

Tags: kubernetes, apache-flink

I am trying to run a Flink job using the Apache Flink Kubernetes operator, and I am trying to host a volume for saving files. This is my deployment so far:

```yaml
  apiVersion: flink.apache.org/v1beta1
  kind: FlinkDeployment
  metadata:
    name: basic-checkpoint-ha-example
  spec:
    image: flink:1.17
    flinkVersion: v1_17
    flinkConfiguration:
      taskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots: "2"
      state.savepoints.dir: file:///tmp/savepoints
      state.checkpoints.dir: file:///tmp/checkpoints
    serviceAccount: flink
    jobManager:
      resource:
        memory: "2048m"
        cpu: 1
    taskManager:
      resource:
        memory: "2048m"
        cpu: 1
    podTemplate:
      spec:
        initContainers:
          - name: init-flink
            image: busybox
            command: ["sh", "-c", "mkdir -p /tmp/checkpoints /tmp/savepoints"]
            volumeMounts:
              - mountPath: /tmp
                name: flink-volume
        containers:
          - name: flink-main-container
            volumeMounts:
              - mountPath: /tmp
                name: flink-volume
        volumes:
          - name: flink-volume
            persistentVolumeClaim:
              claimName: flink-data-pvc
    job:
      jarURI: local:///opt/flink/examples/streaming/StateMachineExample.jar
      parallelism: 2
      upgradeMode: savepoint
      state: running
      savepointTriggerNonce: 0

  ---
  apiVersion: v1
  kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
  metadata:
    name: flink-data-pvc
  spec:
    resources:
      requests:
        storage: 10Gi
    volumeMode: Filesystem
    accessModes:
      - ReadWriteOnce
```

I have created a PVC for my job to mount its data, but I get the error:

```
java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /tmp/jaas-5830500690688188948.conf
```

The service account flink has the following permissions:
[image: Image for flink SA permissions]

My EKS cluster has the EBSCSI role, giving it the proper access to write to volumes. I have made custom roles and rolebindings for my SA:

```
  apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
  kind: Role
  metadata:
    name: flink-pv-access-role
  rules:
  - apiGroups: [""]
    resources: ["persistentvolumes", "persistentvolumeclaims"]
    verbs: ["get", "list", "watch", "create", "delete", "update"]
  ---
  apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
  kind: RoleBinding
  metadata:
    name: flink-pv-access-binding
  subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: flink
    namespace: default
  roleRef:
    kind: Role
    name: flink-pv-access-role
    apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

I am unsure how to solve the access denied exception when my code runs. I have create volumes for some StatefulSets, and they seem to be accessing the volumes fine.